# Dynamic elements not created properly in Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote a masking jquery that is suppose to add dynamic elements the an existing input element.

```
var link = $('<a title="show" role="link" href="#" class="masker-value">show</a>');

wrapper: function() {
  container = $(container)
    .attr('ispartial', this.options.partial)
    .attr('readyonly', this.options.readyOnly);
  $(this.element).wrap(container);
  if (!this.options.hideToggle)
    $(this.element).after(link);
}
```

If I have a single input on a page, the code above works fine, but if I have multiple input, the `link` is only added to the last input.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/capiono/nxvdm5hr/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to the `wrapper` function:

```
link = $('<a title="show" role="link" href="#" class="masker-value">show</a>');
```

You defined link globally outside the wrapper function so its always refering to the same object, which gets moved in the DOM.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nxvdm5hr/5/

**Further explanation:**

When you use `$('<a/>')`, jQuery creates an input DOM element.

When you `.after()` that element, it detaches from the previous position.

You could also modify the var `link` to just HTML code, which will also fix your problem.